# Grouping in StringTemplate

Tags: c#, .net, templates, grouping, stringtemplate

I've just begun using StringTemplate (from stringTemplate.org) and I'd like to know how to achieve grouping in the results.

e.g.

> Month , ID
>       __________________________________
>       Jan  ,1
>       Jan  ,2
>       Feb  ,3
>       Feb  ,4
>       Feb  ,5
>       Mar  ,6
>       Mar  ,7
>       Mar  ,8
>       Mar  ,9

so that the results when grouped by month look something like:

> Jan:
>   1
>   2
>   Feb:
>   3
>   4
>   5
>   Mar:
>   6
>   7
>   8
>   9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it all depends on how you send in the data.  ST won't do any computation for you, which normally includes what belongs in what set.

Comment: the data sent could simply be an array of objects that may contain identical Month properties. Or perhaps a datatable.

either way... Is restructuring the source data the only answer?

Comment: I think so.  ST just displays data; it can't group per se.

Comment: If you want more power, I suggest T4, which can do all this and much more (i.e. Using a LINQ GroupBy on your data within the template itself.)

Comment: Indeed Sending in the data properly organised is a key here.
short answer is "no" you cant do it without restructuring the source.
doing a linq groupby isn't too much of an inconvenience anyway.

Comment: I have used ModelAdaptors to produce summary information. Suppose the model has the fields 'month' and 'id' as show above. The custom model adaptor could match on 'monthIdList' and return a list of the months with their ids.

Answer (score 0):

The separation of model and view implies that things like grouping should be done by preparing the model and not in the view. In the ST4 context the model may be prepared in several places.

- During the preparation of the (custom) model
- [Using a Model-Adaptor](https://github.com/antlr/stringtemplate4/blob/master/doc/adaptors.md)
- [Using a Renderer](https://github.com/antlr/stringtemplate4/blob/master/doc/renderers.md)

Each of these approaches has specific cases where they are appropriate.
The [model-adaptor](https://github.com/antlr/stringtemplate4/blob/master/doc/adaptors.md) can be useful when using some non-antlr parser, e.g. [Protoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_Buffers).